# How to add and remove active class dynamically

Tags: angularjs

In my webpage I have 2 languages **English** and **Hindi**. By default my page will be in English.

When I click on Hindi language I want to add active class to `li` which has `hin` id, and want to remove `active` class, which has `eng` id.

```
<li class="lang active" id="eng">
  <a href="" ng-click="myfunc('eng');">ENG </a>
</li>
<li class="lang" id="hin">
  <a href="" ng-click="myfunc('hin');">HIN </a>
</li>
```

Whenever I change language page gets refreshed. I need these changes once page is refreshed

```
myfunc = function(item) {
  $scope.selectedlang = item;           
  var test = {value: item, displayValue: ''};
  c.server.get(test).then(function() {          
    $window.location.reload();      
  })
```

I tried like this.

```
<li ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'eng'}" ng-click="selectedTab = 'eng'">
  <a href="#eng">english</a>
</li>
<li ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'hin'}" ng-click="selectedTab = 'hin'">
  <a href="#hin">hindi</a>
</li>
```

But these changes are not appearing after a page refresh.

**How can I toggle classes using AngularJS?**

Comment: you are not supposed to refresh the page in AngularJS (as SPA). Otherwise save any changes in `localstorage`

Comment: can I achieve it using jquery?

Comment: if you refresh it, it will not be saved no matter what you use

Comment: @AlekseySolovey even If i stored in `localstorage` changes appeared before page refresh only

Comment: @AlekseySolovey But am unable to change page to other language without page refresh

Comment: maybe you should have asked that from the very beginning: _how to change language without refreshing the page_

Comment: @AlekseySolovey is it possible without refresh?pls give me an idea.

Comment: you can try [`angular-translate`](https://angular-translate.github.io/) module. They have a demo and instructions on their website. The text is changed instantly on the whole website if you set it up correctly (Note: it does not translate it for you automatically, you have to do it manually)

Comment: thanks.last question..can I add `active` class on `onload' once page gets refreshed instead of doing it in `ng-click`

Comment: initialise it in your controller, e.g. with `ng-class` set up you need `$scope.selectedTab = "eng";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<li ng-class="{'active':location.hash == '#eng'}"><a href="#eng" >english</a>
</li>
<li ng-class="{'active':location.hash == '#hin'}"><a href="#hin" >hindi</a>
</li>
```

or

```
<li ng-class="{'active':location.hash == '#eng'}" id="eng">
  <a href="" ng-click="myfunc('eng');">ENG </a>
</li>
<li ng-class="{'active':location.hash == '#hin'}" id="hin">
  <a href="" ng-click="myfunc('hin');">HIN </a>
</li>


myfunc = function(item) {
  location.hash = item;
  $scope.selectedlang = item;           
  var test = {value: item, displayValue: ''};
  c.server.get(test).then(function() {          
    $window.location.reload();      
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Store selectedTab value in local storage than refresh page. Once the page is reloaded get value from local storage and assign to selectedlang.

```
myfunc = function (item) {
    $scope.selectedlang = item;
    $window.localStorage.setItem('lang', item);
    var test = {
        value: item,
        displayValue: ''
    };
    c.server.get(test).then(function () {
        $window.location.reload();

    });
}

// On page load
$scope.selectedlang = $window.localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'eng';
```

Comment: you are great!!..But I couldn't understand your idea :-( ..do I need to change anything in html along with localstorage?

Comment: No, you don't have to do anything in HTML. only in the controller, you need to modify. Inject $window in the controller and first line should be `$scope.selectedlang = $window.localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'eng';`

Comment: dont I need to add ng-class in html?

Comment: HTML code is correct `<li ng-class="{'active':selectedTab === 'eng'}" ng-click="selectedTab = 'eng'">
  <a href="#eng">english</a>
</li>`

Comment: but class gets removed after page refresh,

Comment: @user7397787 why do you need to refresh it? changes are applied dynamically (with watchers)

Comment: @user7397787 you are assigning the value to `$scope.selectedlang = item;
` but in ng-class it's `selectedTab`. If you assign it to `$scope.selectedTab` It'll resolve the issue.

Comment: yea I changed that to selectedtab,still its not working:-(

Comment: can I add `active` class on `onload' once page gets refreshed instead of doing it in `ng-click`

Comment: yes, you can do Add the first line inside the controller.  `$scope.selectedTab = $window.localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'eng';`

Answer (score 1):

Here the problem is,Whenever page is refreshed then language is set to default language 'eng'.So try to store language value in localstorage and then apply ng-class.

```
<li ng-class="{'active':selectedTab == 'eng'}" ng-click="selectedTab('en')">
 <a href="#eng">english</a>
 </li>
<li ng-class="{'active':selectedTab == 'hin'}" ng-click="selectedTab('hin')">
<a href="#hin">hindi</a>
</li>


selectedTab= function(item) {
    localStorage.setItem("selectedTab",item);
})
```

Then get this locastorage value on page refersh method.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Could you tell me,How you set your default lang?

Comment: can I add `active` class on `onload' once page gets refreshed instead of doing it in `ng-click`

Comment: Yes,you can do that way also

Answer (score 0):

You can Add the class using ng-class, like this.

```
 ng-class="{active: $index == selected}"
```

Here, .active is added to class list on the condition $index == selected

and to remove the .active from the list, reset the selected by

```
$scope.selected = -1
```